# Error handling when ElementNotVisible in dropdown in Selenium code

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, flex3

I have this following code. Please let me know if there is a way to capture the error and display it when the selectedAVE item is not found in the dropdown.

```
FlexWebDriver
    .call(webDriver,
        "container_app",
        "doFlexClick",
        "TreeNodeItem_com.vmware.ebr2.category/_TreeNodeItem_HGroup1/nodeName",
        "");
Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

DropDownList.clickToOpen(webDriver, "vdrCombo");
Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

FlexMouseEvents.leftClick(webDriver, "automationName=" + selectedAVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Try Catch()` to handle the run time exceptions.

```
Try{
   DropDownList.clickToOpen(webDriver, "vdrCombo");
   Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
   FlexMouseEvents.leftClick(webDriver, "automationName=" + selectedAVE);
  }catch(Throwable e){
     system.out.println(e.getMessage())
    }
```